# Why is my checkbox input always the same?

Tags: forms, xhtml, input, checkbox

I have a form (posted below) and the value submitted for the checkbox does not change.  I added the value attribute to the input to try and alleviate this issue but now instead of the debugger always reporting "active" it reports whatever value is set to say "value1" no matter if the box is checked or not.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="f0" method="post" action="">
  <div class="t1">
    <div class="t1_r1">
      <div class="t1_c1"><p class="c"></p></div>
      <div class="t1_c1"><p class="c">Email</p></div>
      <div class="t1_c1"><p class="c">Password</p></div>
      <div class="t1_c1"><p class="c">Keep me logged in<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="f0a" value="value1" /></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="t1_r1">
      <div class="t1_c1"><input class="te6" type="text" name="f0b" /></div>
      <div class="t1_c1"><input class="te6" type="password" name="f0c" /></div>
      <div class="t1_c2"><a id="f0d" href ="javascript:void(0)" class='but'>Login</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id=fb1 class="t1_r1">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I put the elements in a string of text using this function which works fine for the other two inputs.  I updated it to reflect the answer.  This has not been tested yet.

```js
function is(a)
{
  var b = '';
  var c = document.forms[a].elements;
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
  {
    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' && c[i].checked == false)
    {
      b += c[i].name + "=NULL&";
    }
    else
    { 
      b += c[i].name + "=" + c[i].value + "&";
    }
  }
  b = b.slice(0, -1);
  return b;
}
```

Comment: Well, that seems counter-intuitive, and [against the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) (according to html 4, at least). Can you post a link to a live demo that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Sorry, no live demo, I tried taking it out of the <p> tag but this did not help. Is there something special about checkboxes I should know?

Comment: Only that, according to the W3 (follow the link in my first comment) "[when] a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful." So I can't see why your checkbox would be submitted regardless of its being checked or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because with checkboxes, `.value` always returns the text that's in the `value` attribute that you've set in the HTML.  What you need to do is check the `checked` property to see if it's true.  Something like:

```js
function is(a) {
   var b = '';
   var c = document.forms[a].elements;
   for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      var value = "";
      if (c[i].type == "checkbox") {
         value = (c[i].checked) ? c[i].value : "";
      } else {
         value = c[i].value;
      }
      b += c[i].name + "=" + value + "&";
   }
   b = b.slice(0, -1);
   return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes, despite their simple appearance, are more complicated than text - [Sending Checkbox Values Link](http://www.redips.net/javascript/sending-checkbox-values/).